# Why one function requires binding and the other doesn't?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I just started learning React and JavaScript.
While going through the tutorial, I got to this example code of a component, which creates a toggle button:

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {isToggleOn: true};
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
        }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

The way I see it, both `handleClick` and `render` functions use the class's `this` object, which is out of their scope (right?).

So why do I only need to bind it into `handleClick`?

Comment: I never used react, but my guess is that the `onClick` function call replaces the `this` keyword with the `window` object or something similar. This actually happens with the default `addEventListener` method that calls the callback with `this` = `window`. Probably because `handeClick` is called by the `window`, the `this` keyword has to be bound so it isn't over-written by `window` or whoever calls the click function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any react class, functions like componentWillMount, componentDidMount, render etc are called by react internally while rendering the elements and we never call these methods.

Now since the scope is decided while calling, it's react's job to call/bind these methods with appropriate scope.So we do not need to bother about these functions.

However the other functions like handleClick in above example is a method made by us and react does not know anything about it. Also this method's call is defined by us (i.e. when the button is clicked). So here it is our job to call/bind this method with right scope.

That is why we only bind handleClick and not render function in above example.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript assigns scope when calling, not when defining. You need to `bind()` your `handleClick()` method to the class so that when it's called from the the template it can still access the class' scope via `this`.

React templates are compiled into javascript functions, so if you didn't `bind()` your `onClick={this.handleClick}` handler would be scoped to the template function that called it. In your case, it would refer to the button that was clicked.

If your event handler never referred to `this` it wouldn't need binding, but since you're calling `this.setState()` then binding is necessary to keep the handler aware of the class scope.

Comment: i believe that otherwise, `this` would refer to the button that fired the event.

Comment: @sweaver2112 thanks, I updated my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: Isn't  `render()` the "template function that called it", and not the button? And `render()` is in the same class so it's supposed to share the same `this`?